# DidSelectItem deleting the wrong cells when I use it on a collection view

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have a Search bar set up to filter my cells i have a second array that holds the filtered data to show up on the collectionView

I have coded it so that When you select a cell it takes you to another view controller that shows more details of the user I have an edit button on that new controller when you press it, it shows a alert controller with a delete button

When I select a cell without using the search bar and go to the second view controller with the details of the user and use the delete function it works fine

But when i use the search bar and the filtered cells show and i try deleting the one i select on for some reason it deletes whatever cell was on the main array on the same indexPath but does nothing to the cell that I want to delete

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let contactDetailsVC = ContactDetailsVC()
    contactDetailsVC.delegate = self


    if isFiltering == true {

        contactDetailsVC.navigationItem.title = filteredUsers[indexPath.item].name
        contactDetailsVC.nameLabel.text = filteredUsers[indexPath.item].name
        contactDetailsVC.emailLabel.text = filteredUsers[indexPath.item].email


    } else {

        contactDetailsVC.navigationItem.title = user[indexPath.item].name
        contactDetailsVC.nameLabel.text = user[indexPath.item].name
        contactDetailsVC.emailLabel.text = user[indexPath.item].email

    }

    navigationController?.pushViewController(contactDetailsVC, animated: true)

    path =   indexPath.row

}

func deleteCell() {

    print(" delete function called")

    user.remove(at: path)
    collectionView.reloadData()

    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete depending on `isFiltering` like in `didSelect`. And it's more efficient to delete the item rather than reloading the entire collection view

```
func deleteCell() {

    print(" delete function called")
    if isFiltering {
       filteredUsers.remove(at: path)
    } else {
       user.remove(at: path)
    }
    collectionView.deleteItems(at: [path])

    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

Comment: That works well the delete function removes Data from the filtered array but still holds the same user details on the main array                                                                                                                                                     do you know how I can remove it from the original array as well                             I'm pretty new to Swift so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Get the index of the item in the main array with `firstIndex(where:` and remove the item.